# When should I need the constant of integration when I calculate electric potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

For example, electric potential is given by the formula.

$$V = -\int_\infty^a \vec{E} d\vec{l}$$

For some questions, I would just use this formula to get the potential and it would be the correct answer.

But sometimes, I would be given boundary conditions like
$$V = V_{r} \quad at \quad a=r$$
in the case of sphere for example,

then I have to calculate the potential as

$$V = -\int_0^r \vec{E} d\vec{l} + C$$
C calculated by putting in the boundary conditions.

I've been doing this just routinely but I came to wonder what's the difference.

Comment: You don't have constants of integration in definite integration.

Comment: $V= -\int_{r_{0}}^{r} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl}$ . Calculate this expression. Then substitute your boundary conditions in to find $r_{0}$. You  can also solve $V = \int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} + C$ and then plug conditions in. This last one comes from the gradient relation between v and E

Answer (score 0):

The energy/potential origin can be chosen arbitrarily. With potential one usually takes the reference point at $\infty$, which corresponds to the last OP equation with $C=0$. This is however not an obligation, and constant $C$ accounts for that.

More generally, one could write
$$
V=-\int_{\mathbf{r}_0}^\mathbf{a}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l},
$$
where
$$
V(\mathbf{r}_0)=0
$$

Comment: So what does the constant C exactly account for? I got that it is not the constant of integration since it is definite integration.

Comment: It accounts for the fact that the lower limit of integration is not the reference point. Essentially, $C$ is the integral from the reference point to whatever point you have chosen as the lower limit of integration. E.g., $\int_{\infty}^a=\int_{\infty}^0+\int_0^a=C+\int_0^a$

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential being defined in a gradient, you can add any constant to it without changing its properties.

As long as you're using it in computations like integral on a curve, like voltage, the constant cancels out automaticaly. Thats's why you don't need to know what the constant is when using a voltmeter.

There are, however, norms in physics to decide where to put the origin of potentials, which is equivalent to giving a value to this constant.

- In electricity, when there are devices connected to the ground, then the ground is usually used as the point where potential is zero.
- In electrostatic, if the source of the field has a finite size, the potential is typically chosen to be zero at infinity.
- In electrostatic, if the source has an infinite size (infinite plane, infinite wire...) then you have to choose one specific point or line where the potential is zero.

Also, if the potential is defined piecewise, you usually assume continuity as long as there are only volumetric or surface charge distributions.

In a nutshell, the constant has no deep physical meaning, but when speaking about potential instead of voltage is useful, it's convenient to assign a value to it, either to make expressions simpler or as a choice of origin.

Comment: So you mean that either putting the boundary conditions into the first equation $$V = -\int_\infty^a \vec{E} d\vec{l}$$ or the second equation $$V = -\int_0^r \vec{E} d\vec{l} + C$$ it will bring the same result.

Comment: Perhaps you're conflating primitive and integrale. Let $f$ be a function and $F$ a primitive. $F$ isn't unique, you can add any constant to it. The integrale of $f$ on $[a,b]$, on the hand, has a unique value that doesn't depend on the constant chosen for the primitive. In electrostatic, the potential is a primitive of $\vec{E}$, while voltage is a (line) integrale of $\vec{E}$.